# DynamoDBMapper.save() using Private Constructor

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, builder

I'd like to save DynamoDB objects that use a private constructor because I'm utilizing a builder pattern. But as of now, I'm getting the following:

```
DynamoDBMappingException: could not instantiate class
```

Does anyone see a way around this?